# How to extract envelope for piecewise defined function?

Tags: plotting, piecewise, envelope

I have a plot generated from an ugly and complex set of piece-wise functions. I'm looking to extract the envelope function from this data set. I've tried a lot of suggestions in other threads, but none seem to contain information about dealing with piece-wise functions. I've tried using a Fourier series, but that didn't seem to give me what I was looking for. The plot is located below[image]

Comment: Can you provide the actual data?

Comment: Try a MaxFilter with a window about 2 or 3 units wide to extract the upper envelope. MinFilter will get the lower envelope, though from the look of your graph, this may not be interesting.